# Control the fps in Adobe Flash effectively

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs4, frame-rate

I am working on a splash page in Adobe Flash CS4. It is to be used in various flash works - differing in ActionScript versions and framerate.

The animation itself contain multiple tweens, even nested ones. If I am to use it with a different framerate, I'll have to alter a lot of frames to make it work smoothly in the new fps.

What are the options I have to do this effectively? 
Is there a technique by which I can swicth to the animation's frame rate during it's playtime and switch back to the original fps once it is done?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the FPS with [stage.frameRate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate) (Flash Player 9+) and you could then restore it to its original value (previously stored in a variable) after the animation ends.